# Video cast on Fire TV stick using google cast

Tags: android, ios, youtube-api, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I am using [Google cast SDK](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers#setup_for_development) for casting video in TV for android and ios application. Using this SDK I am able to cast video in Android TV, chromcast, But **Fire TV stick** device is not found in SDK. I want to implement video casting same like youtube. I research about it but not found any useful content. I have some question:

1. Is google cast SDK support to cast video on Fire TV Stick or Ruko TV?
2. What api used by youtube for casting video on Fire TV stick?

Answer (score 0):

i think your answer for

1.Is google cast SDK support to cast video on Fire TV Stick or Ruko TV?
is here

https://www.alphr.com/how-to-mirror-chrome-to-a-firestick/

Comment: I want to enable casting for my own app, without using default setting cast option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your question's answer

1. Is google cast SDK support to cast video on Fire TV Stick or Ruko TV?

- Yes you can cast video with a firestick. You have to download the AirScreen app in your firestick device. AirScreen allows you to cast video like youtube. I am testing with the firestick device in my app too and it works fine. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ionitech.airscreen&hl=en_IN&gl=US)

2. You have to call loadMedia api to cast video in firestick

here is an example which I used to cast video in firestick and other Chromecast devices.

```
 global.currentSession.client.loadMedia({
            autoplay: true,
            mediaInfo: {
              contentUrl:
                'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4',
              contentType: 'application/mp4', //content type is type of your video
              contentId:
                'https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4', //ContentId is compulsory othervise video will not show
              id: '5',
              metadata: {
                // type: 'movie',
                title: 'Test Title ',
                images: [
                  {
                    url: 'https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/43/23/83/360_F_143238306_lh0ap42wgot36y44WybfQpvsJB5A1CHc.jpg',
                  },
                ],
              },
              customData: {
                type: 'application/mp4',
              },
            },
            repeatMode: 'all',
          });
```